# How to get the City from address column in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I am trying to get the city from the Purchase Address column, my code is like below:
when I tried [0] or [-1], I can get the street address or the state/zip. But when I try [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQqQP.png), it raised the error: index out of range?
Can anyone help solve this problem?
[when I try to get the street address, it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQqQP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbxSY.png)

This is the result when I tried [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQqQP.png), since city is in the middle of the address
[when I try to get the city, it raise error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyxWd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please paste your code and data into your question as [formatted text](/editing-help). Please do not upload images to represent text: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

we need minimal and reproducible example for answer. also need text or code not image.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a,B,c', 'a,C,b', 'd'], columns=['col1'])
```

`df`

```
    col1
0   a,B,c
1   a,C,b
2   d
```

---

**Code**

your code :

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
```

IndexError: list index out of range

try following code:

```
out = df['col1'].str.split(',').str[1]
```

`out`

```
0      B
1      C
2    NaN
Name: col1, dtype: object
```